# Reactjs issue with npm start

Tags: reactjs, networking, module, localhost, package.json

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-07T06_09_27_133Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Brandlly>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Posting a question with just a stack trace will likely get you downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. did your `package.json` contain script `start` or `star`, check your spelling.
2. you have `package.json` on your working diretory.

ex:

```
  // package.json
  "scripts": {
     // other script...
     "start": ...
  },
```